# Prevent dplyr from printing column classes

Tags: r, dplyr

The [new release](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases) of `dplyr` contains a [new feature](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/1276) that will print the class of each column when printing a data frame with class `tbl_df`, or using `head` or `tail`. Is there a way to turn this feature off? Similar to using `options(dplyr.width = Inf)` to have it print every variable in a data frame, not just the ones that fit on the screen. I can't seem to find a list of `dplyr` options anywhere online.

Edit: Cleared up the issue is when printing `tbl_df` data frames not just any plain data frame.

Comment: It looks like it was supposed to be `options(dplyr.print_show_classes = F)` but in the pull request you linked 
Hadley decided it should be always on

Comment: @jeremycg yea both that and just `options(dplyr.show_classes = F)` do nothing to alleviate it. I saw that comment by Hadley but I assumed he would at least leave it as an option even if it wasn't the default one.